# Is there is a facility in docusign show link on website?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to explain a scenario.I have two person A and B , A is a person who will mark where to sign document. B is a person who will sign document.

Now A will visit to my website upload document.Then redirect to docusign and mark where to sign and redirect to website.
Now B will "**visit to my website click on link**" sign the document redirect back to website.

Problem here is i do not want email involved and i am not able to "find link" where B can visit.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build an integration that does what you just describe. Person A would be using embedded sending so that they can add documents and places tags and then the system would be ready for person B. Person B would be using embedded signing. If you want the link for that to live more than 2 minutes, you would need to use a redirect from your system, where your app generates the link on the fly.

Comment: But how we will have same document which is at time of embeded sending.then same document document signing.kindly explain in detail.this problem ( i did that by envolope id ) , can we have better alternative/idea.

Comment: envelopeID is the way to go. Why is that not a good option for you?

Comment: some time It says Message: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body: O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:9:"errorCode";s:22:"USER_LACKS_PERMISSIONS";s:7:"message";s:88:"This User lacks sufficient permissions. User does not have permissions to clone envelope";}

Comment: aha, this is an interesting one, I'll have to research this, but can you make sure that user is an admin?

Comment: Amit, can you provide your accountID so we can research this? you can email it to me at inbar.gazit@docusign.com

Comment: thanks, it appears you are using two different accounts. The envelope is coming from one account and the API is using a different account